# Promisify in redis client violates eslint rules

Tags: typescript, eslint, node-redis, typescript-eslint, node-promisify

I wanted to use redis client with `promisify`:

```
import type { RedisClient } from "redis";
import * as util from "util";

class MyClass {
  private redisClient: RedisClient;

  constructor(client: RedisClient) {
    this.redisClient = client;
  }

  getMyData = (): SomeType[] => {
    const getAsync: Promise<string | undefined> = util.promisify(this.redisClient.get).bind(this.redisClient);
 // ...
  };
}
```

However I ran into two issues with eslint:

1. `ESLint: Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of 'this'.(@typescript-eslint/unbound-method)` at `this.redisClient.get` fragment

and

2. `ESLint: Unsafe assignment of an any value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment)` at `getAsync`

How I can use `promisify` in a way that will be type aware and proper `this` scoping?

Comment: Have you tried `util.promisify(this.redisClient.get.bind(this.redisClient))`

Comment: it resolves the first issue, thanks! do you know how I can resolve the second one as well?

Comment: try this: `const getAsync = util.promisify<string|undefined>(this.redisClient.get.bind(this.redisClient))`

Comment: works! can you convert your comments to answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first eslint error, you are binding `this` to the wrong method.

In the second error, you are telling Typescript what return type  `getAsync` should hold, instead you need to tell `promisify` what is the return value that your are trying to promisify.

This should fix both eslint errors:

```
import type { RedisClient } from "redis";
import * as util from "util";

class MyClass {
  private redisClient: RedisClient;

  constructor(client: RedisClient) {
    this.redisClient = client;
  }

  getMyData = (): SomeType[] => {
    const getAsync = util.promisify<string |undefined>(this.redisClient.get.bind(this.redisClient))

  };
}
```